# unable to display image in listview

Tags: android, listview, imageview

I am unable to display images but the text is displayed.

I have modified the code from http://mobile.dzone.com/news/android-tutorial-how-parse  to the code below.

I would prefer using SimpleAdapter only .Is it possible? As I have implemented the same code as below everywhere.

Or little modifications to the below code would be fine.

How do I display images?

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist;
    SimpleAdapter adapter;

    ProgressDialog pd ;
     ListView lv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);


        mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        new loadingDisplayClass().execute();
    }

    public class loadingDisplayClass extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
             pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pd.setTitle("Loading......");
            pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            pd.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String url = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topalbums/limit=50/json";

            JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(url);


            try {
                JSONObject arr2 = json.getJSONObject("feed");
                JSONArray arr = arr2.getJSONArray("entry");

                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject e1 = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                    JSONArray jsar = e1.getJSONArray("im:image");

                    JSONObject jsname = e1.getJSONObject("im:name");
                    String name = jsname.getString("label");


                    JSONObject jso = e1.getJSONObject("im:artist");
                    String lbl = jso.getString("label");

                        JSONObject e12 = jsar.getJSONObject(0);

                    String icon = e12.getString("label");


                     HashMap<String, String> hashmapnew = new HashMap<String, String>();


                    hashmapnew.put("icons", icon);

                    hashmapnew.put("name", name);
                    hashmapnew.put("artist", lbl);

                    mylist.add(hashmapnew);

                    publishProgress(((int) ((i + 1 / (float) arr.length()) * 100)));


                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Network communication error!", 5).show();
            }

             adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), mylist,
                    R.layout.list, new String[] {
                            "icons","name","artist" },
                    new int[] { R.id.image,R.id.name,R.id.artist });

            return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... integers) {

            pd.incrementProgressBy(integers[0]);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);


            setListAdapter(adapter);


            pd.dismiss();

               lv = getListView();

            lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv
                            .getItemAtPosition(position);


                }
            });
        }

    }




}
```

Comment: +1 for quick learning

Comment: Really appreciate your time Sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am unable to display images but the text is displayed

Images won't display because you are just passing url to the SimpleAdapter.In order to show images you need to first download the images in the url returned above service .

You need to create a custom Adapter and display images by downloading them

Downloading each image and displaying image in imageView takes lot time and as the listview recycle views your images will always download when the list is scrolled. So what you need to do is to use [-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)  or [Lazy List](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) to provide automatic downloading and caching images.

Comment: So how do I change the above code by passing url as you have asked using any which you feel is good ?

Comment: @JamesPatrick You need to create a customAdapter and download images in it. I have given a link in the answer to Lazy List project, check that..And one of the example http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: Can I add it to my already existing code or Start from scratch.

Comment: @JamesPatrick You just need to create a custom adapter and there pass your url to universal imagedownloader, it will display your image. There are no changes except that

Comment: **So I need to remove this line :** adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), mylist,
                    R.layout.list, new String[] {
                            "icons","name","artist" },
                    new int[] { R.id.image,R.id.name,R.id.artist });

Comment: **And add** adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, mylist); and modify the code in LazyAdapter ?

Comment: Nope...You need to create a customAdapter..Lazy Adapter is example that will only work that list..

Comment: @JamesPatrick check this tutorial, there he created a custom adapter http://www.javasrilankansupport.com/2012/05/android-listview-example-with-image-and.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27168/discussion-between-james-patrick-and-pragnani)

Comment: But in that tutorial it has drawable and not http request

Comment: @JamesPatrick I can give away the code, but you won't learn anything when I do that.. so Learn it by your self. Try to search in google about listView with images and Lazy list you'll find many posts describing the same

Comment: Please share the code for the above It will be a great help .I am currently looking into AndroidHive project.

Comment: I have updated the code let us continue this discussion in chat .

Comment: I have a query regarding the above code please check the chat discussion .Thank You Sir.

Comment: I have updated the code in the discussion also have created a new question :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799663/listview-lazyadapter    .Please help me out Sir.

Comment: Posted another question on  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816590/hashmap-working-in-simpleadapter-but-not-working-in-customm-array-adapter